# Docker Swarm Current State Pending

Tags: docker-swarm

I cannot deploy anymore containers to my Docker Swarm. For example after removing the stack and then deloying, the containers (services) stay at CURRENT STATE Pending for hours and nothing happens.

```
ID             NAME                                           IMAGE                                             NODE      DESIRED STATE   CURRENT STATE            ERROR     PORTS
izwihmd5v5tj   my-prod_db-local.1       postgres:11                                                 Running         Pending 5 hours ago
```

When you run docker inspect < ID > you get no error, but just message: "pending task scheduling":

```
    "Status": {
        "Timestamp": "2023-12-27T13:55:35.786013412Z",
        "State": "pending",
        "Message": "pending task scheduling",
        "PortStatus": {}
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I am running 3 masters. I first restarted dockerd on the first two, but with no help. However, the third dockerd master was throwing stack trace (from /var/log/syslog)

```
Dec 27 16:17:36 server dockerd[2461573]: goroutine 1 [running, locked
to thread]: Dec 27 16:17:36 server dockerd[2461573]:
github.com/docker/docker/pkg/stack.dump(0xc00019e000?) Dec 27 16:17:36
server dockerd[2461573]:
#011/root/build-deb/engine/pkg/stack/stackdump.go:49 +0x5c Dec 27 16:17:36 server dockerd[2461573]:
github.com/docker/docker/pkg/stack.Dump(...) Dec 27 16:17:36 server
dockerd[2461573]: #011/root/build-deb/engine/pkg/stack/stackdump.go:18
Dec 27 16:17:36 server dockerd[2461573]:
github.com/docker/docker/daemon/cluster.(*Cluster).Cleanup(0xc0000559e0)
Dec 27 16:17:36 server dockerd[2461573]:
#011/root/build-deb/engine/daemon/cluster/cluster.go:396 +0x325 Dec 27 16:17:36 server dockerd[2461573]:
main.(*DaemonCli).start(0xc00059a040, 0xc000bfcfc0) Dec 27 16:17:36
server dockerd[2461573]:
#011/root/build-deb/engine/cmd/dockerd/daemon.go:307 +0x1765 Dec 27 16:17:36 server dockerd[2461573]: main.runDaemon(...) Dec 27 16:17:36
server dockerd[2461573]:
#011/root/build-deb/engine/cmd/dockerd/docker_unix.go:14 Dec 27 16:17:36 server dockerd[2461573]:
main.newDaemonCommand.func1(0xc000c28000?, {0xc000598060?, 0x1?, 0x1?})
```

Running

```
systemctl restart docker
```

on the crashing master fixed the issue